# Apply regex to a DataFrame after groupby to filter values in a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
            text   row
0     string1111  14.0
1     string1234  14.0
2     strin1gabc  12.0
3  anotherstring  12.0
4          12351  15.0
```

I am trying to group by `row` and concatenate `text` for each `row`, then remove all numbers from the concatenated `text`. I am successful in the group by, however, I am not sure how to apply a regex to remove numbers from the resulting DataFrame.

The below code returns an unfiltered DataFrame

```
x = df.groupby(['row'], as_index=False).agg({'text': ' '.join})
```

The desired output is something that looks like this

```
        text                   row
0     string string            14.0
1     stringabc anotherstirng  12.0
```

How do I apply a regex to filter out text only on the grouped by dataframe? it is preferred that the filter is applied to the resulting dataFrame and not the original one, as the original one is used in other functions that will use the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for replace column by values without numbers, then aggregate, change columns order and last remove rows filled by empty strings by converting column to `bool`:

```
x = (df.assign(text = df['text'].str.replace('\d', ''))
       .groupby('row', sort=False)['text']
       .agg( ' '.join)
       .reset_index()[['text','row']]
       .loc[lambda x: x['text'].astype(bool)])
print (x)
                      text   row
0            string string  14.0
1  stringabc anotherstring  12.0
```